# stepper component using angular similar to one in

Tags: angular, angular-material-stepper, transferwise

I am building a simple angular4 application and would like to add a stepper component. I am looking similar to the one attached below in one of the website. The source code is given in react. But i need in angular2/4.

Has anyone implemented a similar component? If so could you please direct me the right path?

Thanks
[transferwise website](https://github.com/transferwise/components/tree/master/src/stepper)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check our (TransferWise) components library: https://transferwise.github.io/components/ (see Flow Navigation section)

Answer (score 1):

You can download from here: https://github.com/jorgecavaleiro/angular-stepper , the full source code of an Angular 5 stepper component build from scratch.

Comment: how to make he steps horizontal in a simple option that can be passed to the component?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material has stepper. Chek link below
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: thanks. but i am looking something similar to the one i have shown here. :)

Comment: You can achieve it with some small UI changes to angular material. You can check on angular.io resources tab for other UI supporting libraries and check if they have what you are looking for.
https://angular.io/resources